# How can i foward funds swaped from 0x api quotes in the same transaction

Tags: 0x, delegatecall, meta-transactions, batch

ideally i will like to add more logic (like fowarding funds or fees) to the quote.data before letting a user send the transaction to the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to create a quote that includes affiliate fee and that fee be forwarded to an address.

On the 0x docs api documention here: https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-quote#request you have the fields feeRecipient and buyTokenPercentage which could be used to get a fee on top of your quote.

For instance: https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=DAI&sellToken=WETH&sellAmount=100000000000000000&buyTokenPercentageFee=0.1&feeRecipient=0x5bd68b4d6f90bcc9f3a9456791c0db5a43df676d

You are getting a quote here to buy DAI with WETH, with a percentage fee of 0.1% that will be attributed to address 0x5bd68b4d6f90bcc9f3a9456791c0db5a43df676d